# Value list smart filter bar field of smart table not present despite being configured

Tags: sapui5, sap-gateway

I'm having trouble creating a value list for a field in the smart filter bar of a smart table.

I have an entity set ApplicationsOverviewItemSet with the following entity type definition in SEGW:
[image: Definition of entity ApplicationsOverviewItemSEt]
The smart table has to display this entity set's data. In its smart filter bar I'd like there to be a value list for the statute property. I defined another entity set called ApplicationStatuteSet with this SEGW entity type definition:
[image: Definition of entity ApplicationStatute]
This entity set should be a list of possible statute values and their descriptions. I implemented its GET method in the extended data provider class, making sure to support all pagination query options ($top, $skip and $inlinecount). A basic GET query of the entity set now returns the following data in JSON format:

```
{
    "d": {
        "results": [
            {
                "__metadata": {
                    "id": "https://WEBWSD.<my company>:443/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZC_AD_SCHOLAR_SRV/ApplicationStatuteSet('007')",
                    "uri": "https://WEBWSD.<my company>:443/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZC_AD_SCHOLAR_SRV/ApplicationStatuteSet('007')",
                    "type": "ZC_AD_SCHOLAR_SRV.ApplicationStatute"
                },
                "STATUTE": "007",
                "DESCR": "Visiting scholar"
            },
            {
                "__metadata": {
                    "id": "https://WEBWSD.<my company>:443/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZC_AD_SCHOLAR_SRV/ApplicationStatuteSet('014')",
                    "uri": "https://WEBWSD.<my company>:443/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZC_AD_SCHOLAR_SRV/ApplicationStatuteSet('014')",
                    "type": "ZC_AD_SCHOLAR_SRV.ApplicationStatute"
                },
                "STATUTE": "014",
                "DESCR": "International scholar"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I adjusted the extended model provider class to generate the following annotation in the service metadata document designating the ApplicationStatute entity as a value list provider for statute fields:

```
<Annotations Target="ZC_AD_SCHOLAR_SRV.ApplicationStatute" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm">
    <Annotation Term="com.sap.vocabularies.Common.v1.ValueList">
        <Record>
            <PropertyValue Property="Label" String="Statutes"/>
            <PropertyValue Property="CollectionPath" String="ApplicationStatuteSet"/>
            <PropertyValue Property="SearchSupported" Bool="true"/>
            <PropertyValue Property="Parameters">
                <Collection>
                    <Record Type="com.sap.vocabularies.Common.v1.ValueListParameterInOut">
                        <PropertyValue Property="LocalDataProperty" PropertyPath="statute"/>
                        <PropertyValue Property="ValueListProperty" String="STATUTE"/>
                    </Record>
                    <Record Type="com.sap.vocabularies.Common.v1.ValueListParameterDisplayOnly">
                        <PropertyValue Property="ValueListProperty" String="DESCR"/>
                    </Record>
                </Collection>
            </PropertyValue>
        </Record>
    </Annotation>
</Annotations>
```

I regenerated and reactivated all runtime service artifacts.

In the UI5 front-end view declaration, I explicitly set the preventInitialDataFetchInValueHelpDialog
attribute of the statute field's ControlConfiguration element to false.

AFAIK, this is all one has to do to create a value list for a field.
Howver, if I press F4 in the Statute field of the smart filter bar I only get the following pop-up:

[image: Missing 'Select from list' tab]

The *select from list* tab is missing and there is no value list to be seen …

An example of what I'd like to achieve is the value list that pops up when you press F4 in the Company Code field of [the first SAPUI5 smart table sample app](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/entity/sap.ui.comp.smarttable.SmartTable/sample/sap.ui.comp.sample.smarttable):
[image: 'Select from list' tab available]

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or overlooking in creating the value list for the field?

Thanks in advance for all the help,

Joshua

Answer (score 0):

We found the problem. The annotation target has to refer to the field in the entity to which you want to couple a value list. In my case it had to be "ApplicationsOverviewItem/statute".